# Effecient ways to find the squares enclosed by a path on their edges

Tags: algorithms, geometry

If we have a 2d grid (e.g. points at every (x,y) such that x and y are integers) and a closed path on this grid, such that a point on the path (x,y) could only be followed by a point in [(x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)], what is the most efficient way to find the squares enclosed by this path?

Edit: this isn't a homework question, although it may read like one.

My current approach is, for each square in the grid that could feasibly be part of the path, count how edges are in the same column, below the square. If this is odd the square is enclosed, and if it is even, it is not.

This is O(n^{3}), where n is the width of the path. Is there a better way?

To make "efficient" more precise: lower time complexity.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)** "...If your question on Programmers.SE is just a copy paste of homework problem, expect it to be downvoted, closed, and deleted - potentially in quite short order."

Comment: Terrible homework question, by the way, unless the word "efficient" is defined somewhere and not mentioned here.

Comment: Apparently the most efficient way is to ask someone else.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of this so that we can understand what you're talking about?  I know what a square is, and presumably you have squares drawn on a grid of points, but what is a path?  Can the squares be turned sideways?  Overall, your problem is under-specified.

Comment: Also, don't forget to ask yourself when a solution is fast enough. It's a typical mistake to want to optimize out of a sense of efficiency-pleasing, rather than performance goals. We've all been there. Is your `O(n^3)` approach really not fast enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the minimum enclosing rectangle. Scan each row of the rectangle counting edge crossings. When the count is odd, a square is inside the rectangle, when even then outside.

```
----------         ----------
| inside | outside | inside |
|        |---------|        |
```

Comment: Just to clarify - for each grid point in the row, you count the number of edge crossing between that point and the nearest side of the rectangle?  If the count is odd then the grid is inside the closed path and if even it's outside?

Comment: @DanPichelman: just scan each row left to right keeping track.